# linked dropdown controls?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

i want to link 2 drop downs in an asp.net application.

they will contain release and project data such that each release will have multiple projects.

whats the best and most efficient way to do this?

I was thinking to use ajax for this but dont want a server call each time a new release is selected since this will typically not change ofter so now i am thinking to use caching and bind them to cache objects and havea  data dependancy to refresh teh cash once new data is detected.

thoughts?
examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quite like the CascadingDropDown control extenders in the Ajax Control Toolkit. Take a look. It might fit the bill.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx